# Java servlet java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

Tags: java, servlets, javac

I have a very simple servlet,when I add the JSON library and try to run it i have `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject` (without the json library every thing works fine).
I am compiling like this (in ubuntu) :

```
javac  -classpath ":./libs/json-20160810.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar:." *.java && mv *.class /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/
```

It compiles without any errors, it occurs at runtime.

I am not using any IDE for this.

The servlet is running in a docker:

the docker file :

```
FROM tomcat:7

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install default-jdk --yes

COPY . /src

WORKDIR /src/

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes

RUN javac  -classpath ./libs/json-20160810.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar:. *.java && mv *.class /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/

RUN cp web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF
```

Comment: add this in web.xml, <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20080701</version>
</dependency>

Comment: still the same problem @Jens

Comment: put json-20160810.jar in your tomcat lib folder

Comment: @SandeepRoy Looks like op do not use maven. Also you can not add a dependency in a web.xml

Comment: yes ,I have libs directory in the folder @Jens

Comment: yes in the libs folder @Jens

Comment: How do you run your application. You only Shows the compile Statement, which confused me

Comment: I didn't mention that it runs in a Docker,I am adding the docker file @Jens

Comment: as @kuhajeyan mentioned, the json...jar is not in your tomcat classpath.

Comment: you mean I need to add it to the docker file also ? @Jens

Comment: Yes or better build awar which contains the dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to add a line to copy the JSON jar to your application's WEB-INF/lib instead of Tomcat lib as your application uses it, not tomcat itself

Comment: Solved the problem.@Peter Gelderbloem

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide json libraries in classpath when you run the application as well. Easiest way would be put them in your tomcat's lib folder
put json-20160810.jar in lib of tomcat

Comment: I need to create lib folder ? because i don't see it . @kuhajeyan

Comment: @Maximtoyberman there should be 'lib' folder in tomcat installation. or you need to create a one

Comment: Putting the jar into tomcat lib is not a good idea. What is if the app is deployed on another server?